# Why would a template class have an unused type?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming, template-classes, boost-units

I'm reviewing the boost units library and I am puzzled why the boost::units::unit class has an extra template parameter.   Here is the example:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/units/unit.hpp

```
template<class Dim,class System, class Enable>
class unit
{
    public:
        typedef unit<Dim, System>   unit_type;
        typedef unit<Dim,System>    this_type;
        typedef Dim                 dimension_type; 
        typedef System              system_type;

        unit() { }
        unit(const this_type&) { }
        //~unit() { }  

        this_type& operator=(const this_type&) { return *this; }

        // sun will ignore errors resulting from templates
        // instantiated in the return type of a function.
        // Make sure that we get an error anyway by putting.
        // the check in the destructor.
        #ifdef __SUNPRO_CC
        ~unit() {
            BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((detail::check_system<System, Dim>));
            BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((is_dimension_list<Dim>));
        }
        #else
    private:
        BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((detail::check_system<System, Dim>));
        BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((is_dimension_list<Dim>));
        #endif
};
```

The class is used to add dimensions to dimension system.

```
typedef unit<pressure_dimension,si::system>      pressure;
```

What purpose would "Enable" serve in this case?

Comment: Maybe some sort of SFINAE?

Comment: @black With a name like `Enable` that's what I would guess too.

Comment: For SFINAE leverage with `enable_if`. See [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That class template is [forward declared in `"units_fwd.hpp"`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/units/units_fwd.hpp).

```
template<class Dim,class System, class Enable=void> class unit;
```

there we see that the 3rd parameter is defaulted to `void`.  I would be tempted to even do `template<class Dim,class System, class=void> class unit;` and also leave it nameless in the implementation, but there may be compiler compatibility or code standards that mean they give it the name `Enable`.

Such an "extra" type allows for SFINAE tests on the first two types.  If you create a specialization where the 3rd type is only valid for some subsets of `Dim` and `System` the extra parameter (defaulted to `void`) lets you do that.

You can even leave your base implementation empty (either `;` or `{};` which have different effects) and only specialize, making arguments that fail your test be treated as invalid options.

Here is a toy example of SFINAE:

```
template<class T, class=void> struct is_int : std::false_type {};
template<class T> struct is_int< T,
  std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<T, int>{} >
> : std::true_type {};
```

the base specialization inherits from `false_type`.  If, however, the type `T` passes my test in the next specialization, it is preferred, and the result inherits from `true_type`.

In this case, we'd be better served by just doing `is_int< int, void >:std::true_type{}`, but in a more complex situation (say, `is_integral`) we can do a nearly arbitrary compile-time check and use it to enable or disable the `true_type` specialization.